# if and empty behavior oddity

Tags: php, if-statement, string

When I write

```
$char='a' 
if (!empty($char)){
   echo 'true';
} else {
   echo 'false';
}
```

I get true, but when:

```
if ($char='a' && !empty($char)){
   echo 'true';
} else {
   echo 'false';
}
```

Why I get 'false'?

Comment: You missed `==` instead of `=` in second piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the second way is the same as:

```
if ($char = ('a' && !empty($char))){
   echo 'true';
} else {
   echo 'false';
}
```

`&&` has higher precedence than `=`, so `$char` will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

because you are writing `if($char = 'a' && !empty($char))`, you are using the assigning operator, use `==`, u should get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

Because of single there is single equal sign.

```
if ($char='a'
```

indeed

```
if ($char=='a'
```